# use angular and ui-bootstrap make a directive on the modal events bind cant work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

my app use angular 1.3 and ui-bootstrap
and I build some directive in the app
like this

```

```
var DataTableModule= angular.module('Component.DataTable',['ui.bootstrap'])
     .directive('datatable',['$compile','$log',
        function($compile,$log){
           return {

              compile:function($element){
                   $element.on('click','th.header',function(){
                         $log.debug('click event is ok!');
                   })
                   return function link(scope,$element){
                      .....
                   }
              }
           }
        }
    ])
```

```

and if I use on simple page like this:

```
<datatable></datatable>
```

and I click the dom , console will output : click event is ok!

but ,if I use on modal page like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
   <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <datatable></datatable>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">sure</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">cancel</button>
            </div>
</script>
```

and I click the DOM ,is allway not work!

and I dont know why , is something special of the bootstrap modal ?

Answer (score 1):

I think .on() cannot be use with selectors. 
documentation says

```
on() - Does not support namespaces, selectors or eventData
```

angular.element documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element.

this:

```
$element.on('click','th.header',function(){
  $log.debug('click event is ok!');
})
```

should be:

```
$element.children().find('th').on('click',function(){
  $log.debug('click event is ok!');
})
```

Comment: no,is not this problam ,because I use on simple page (not use modal page),can work.

Comment: directive compile function param $element and link function param $element has different thing ?